# How to render some data which are not in the form, but together with the form data?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to implement an event registration functionality with CodeIgniter, to display an event detail and to provide a registration entry.

A user will need to login to register, thus I will save the user information in the session, once he gets logged in, and click register button, a form of name and mobile will show.

What I want to do is to retrieve the information from the form, plus the user information (in session) + the event_id, and then I will render all the information to CI controller to continue the process.

My question here is, we can set a action in form which will directly go to the controller only with the form data, what about the data that I want to add like user_id, event_id (this will be stored in the page under some html tag)? is it possible to render some data which are not in the form, but together with the form data?

Here is my registration form:

```
<body style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">

<form method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URI.'registration_manager/add_registration'; ?>">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="registration_name" placeholder="name">
      <input type="text" name="mobile" id="registration_mobile" placeholder="mobile">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Register">
    </div>
</form>

...

<div event_id="1337"></div>     // I am not sure if this is proper way to store the event_id here?

</body>
```

I want to send the name,mobile, user_id, event_id to registration_manager/add_registration action, what should I do?

Comment: People (Not me BTW) are downvoting this question because it's missing code, which making it impossible to answer. Put some code and you'll probably get the help you need

Comment: Saying something: Please review the guidelines in [Help] for asking questions on StackOverflow. Notice that you're expected to have done basic research, to provide the code you've tried and explain HOW it doesn't work. As it stands, your question is "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller, you probably have something like the following:
`$this->load->view('path/to/form', array('form_data' => $form_data));` which will get load the view, and let you use the values in `$form_data` within that view.

To get this to work with session data, you can load the session information into a variable and pass that through too:

```
$this->load->library('session'); // loads the session library
$session_data = $this->session->userdata(); // loads everything from the session into a variable $session_data
$this->load->view('path/to/form', array(
    'form_data' => $form_data,
    'session_data' => $session_data
    )); // lets you access $form_data and $session_data in the view
```

In your view, you could then have the line similar to:

```
<div event_id="<?php echo $session_data['event_id'];?>"></div>
```

Have a look at the [CodeIgniter Session documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for things you can do with the sessions.

Comment: the event_id should not be stored in session, no? 
what if we have many events, we can't store all of them. the event_id should comes from the html (the content come from DB, I think the event_id should not be stored in session)

Comment: You could store it in the session for the particular event you are looking to load.  Say you were calling event/edit, you could get the ID of the event as part of the loading of the page and then store it into the session.  Once the data have been validated and stored (from the form being posted), you can clear that event ID from the session.  This method will also allow you to check that that the event_id hasn't been tampered with